# Delphi XE + thread + idHttp without memory leaks

Tags: multithreading, delphi, memory-leaks

At first HI ALL and sry for my English.
can somebody share work source with create + destroy threads with simple GET in execute ?

i try do it by myself but always get memory leaks((

i test it with code at end of source

```
initialization
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
```

btw ill Google it 2 week and test many samples... and always have leaks by default =(

delphi XE7 32bit at windows 7 x64

when i press stop button i still see some connections

[image: screenshot]

after closing i get this message

[image: screenshot]

cant post image, need 10 reputation...

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, sButton, sMemo, sEdit,
  sSpinEdit, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP,System.SyncObjs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StartBtn: TsButton;
    StopBtn: TsButton;
    ThreadCount: TsSpinEdit;
    sdt1: TsEdit;
    sm1: TsMemo;
    procedure StartBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StopBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  Thread = class(TThread)
  private
   HTTP : TIdHTTP;
   result:integer;
   InputIndex:integer;
  public
     procedure Local;
     constructor Create(CreateSuspended:boolean);
     destructor Destroy; override;
  protected
     procedure Execute; override;


  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  LocalWork: Boolean;
  target: string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}



constructor Thread.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean);
begin

  Inherited Create(true);
  FreeOnTerminate:=true;

  HTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  HTTP.ReadTimeout := 2000;

  Resume;
end;


destructor Thread.Destroy;
begin


try

  If HTTP.Connected then
  begin
    HTTP.Disconnect(false);
    HTTP.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear();
    HTTP.IOHandler.Close;
    Terminate;
  end;
finally
  WaitFor;
  FreeAndNil(HTTP);
end;

inherited;
end;




procedure Thread.Execute;
begin

while (LocalWork=True) do
   begin
     if LocalWork=true then
        begin


          HTTP.Get(target);
          if HTTP.ResponseCode=200 then
              begin
                result:=1;
              end
          else
              begin
                result:=2;
              end;


          Synchronize(Local);
        end
     else
        begin

          EndThread(0);
        end;


   end;
EndThread(0);
end;




procedure Thread.Local;
begin

if result=1 then Form1.sm1.Lines.Add('Good ');
if result=2 then Form1.sm1.Lines.Add('Bad ');
end;




procedure TForm1.StartBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
i:integer;
begin
  target := sdt1.Text;
  LocalWork := True;
  for I := 0 to ThreadCount.Value-1 do
  begin
    sm1.Lines.Add('Thread createrd '+inttostr(i));
    Thread.Create(true); // создаем замароженный поток
  end;



end;



procedure TForm1.StopBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
LocalWork:=false;

end;


initialization
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

end.
```

Comment: It would be good if you would have shown us your code so we can see where those memory leaks might originate.

Comment: No need to call `EndThread` in the `Execute` method. Don't call `terminate` and `waitfor` inside the destroy destructor. In `TThread.Create` call `inherited Create(false)` and don't call `Resume` at the end.

Comment: thx for answer!
now i get only this leak
http://s21.postimg.org/9c9ts58pz/screenshot_911.png

Answer (score 3):

- Inside the thread constructor, call `inherited Create(false);`. And skip the `Resume` call at the end. The thread will not start until the constructor has finished anyway.
- In the thread `Execute` method, skip the `EndThread` calls, since the thread will handle this when the `Execute` method ends.
- In the `Destroy` destructor, do not call `Terminate` and `Waitfor`. They do not belong there at all. The thread is told to `FreeOnTerminate`, and will do so gracefully.